# The target "MSDeployTestConnection" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to publish my Web Service, and I set the Publish method to Web Deploy.
The Service URL is localhost and the Site/Application is set to Default Web site.  When I try to validate the connection, I get an error stating that :
"the target "MSDeployTestConnection" does not exist in the project".

I have found no help on this problem on the net.  Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and Web Publish are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. Fortunately I had another project that was working, so I compared the .csproj files.

the one with the problem was missing this entry:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

so the import of the Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not running due to it's condition

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

I simply added the property group and everything worked fine.

(note that i'm working in vs2012 but the project was originally created in vs2010. Check your visualstudio version and vstoolpath path)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate). I am still troubleshooting the error and will share any solution when available.

But I do want to point out that the same web deployment process works well with Visual Studio 2012 on my Windows 8 computer.

Comment: Hey, I am running into similar issue, I was wondering if you found a fix for your problem. If so, do you mind posting it as an answer?